# Where is my Disk Space?

Tags: partitioning, disk

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 and i am having trouble with lost disk space i have 130 GB on my main disk where Ubuntu is but i haven't really downloaded any huge applications, the only big applications that i know that taking up disk space is steam and the actual Ubuntu OS(it takes up 7.1 GB) and Steam is about maximum 8 GB so that's about it.

But on my system monitor it says that  there is 93 GB of space left but adding  up the Ubuntu OS(7.1) and steam(max 8 GB) and lets say the small applications take up about 2 GB that equals about 17.1 GB of disk space used, So wheres the rest? But the weird thing is that on this program that was installed with Ubuntu called Disks it says that there is 100 GB left.
[image]

this is what System Monitor says.

[image]

and this is what the program Disks says.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hard disk free space going down?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/578038/hard-disk-free-space-going-down)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the application called `Disk Usage analyzer` from your Dash to show the space of your disk.

[image]

Once launch click on scan filesystem (the hdd icon) and check the result

[image]